# jsp include jsp not reload menu nav bar

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a main jsp and within this jsp in the other jsp divs that are displayed according to the selected menu

when I enter the index jsp it loads all the jsp at the beginning, but when I enter data in the a.jsp and select the b.jsp (which has new information loaded in the a.jsp) it does not reload the jsp

how can I do it??

I do not know if I explained well

index.jsp

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
               <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        Mantenedores <b class="caret"></b>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li class="active"><a href="#a" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" >A</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#b" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">B</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#c" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" >C</a></li>
                    </ul>
               </li>
               
              </ul>
          </div> 

    <div class="tab-content active">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="a">
            <jsp:include page="a.jsp"/>
        </div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="b">
            <jsp:include page="b.jsp"/>
        </div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="c">
            <jsp:include page="c.jsp"/>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by `which has new information loaded in the a.jsp...` ?

Comment: a.jsp creates cars and b.jsp adds the description to the cars created in a.jsp. When I add a car and then go to b.jsp the new car created is not loaded, I have to refresh the whole site again

Comment: yes because `b.jsp` is already loaded before you make any changes in `a.jsp` to make that work you need to reload it or may be ajax would work ..loading content dynamically .

Comment: that I need to see how to do it, with ajax. some help

Comment: can you add content of `a.jsp` and `b.jsp` and how they are related so that i can suggest you more on this?

Comment: a.jsp 

`<label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Car</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mmNombre" maxlength="30" /> <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="save()">Save</button>` 

b.jsp


`<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 getCars();
});
</script>
<select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="cb_cars"> <option value=""> Select...</option> </select>`

Comment: what does `save` function do ? How above writing ajax code inside that function and appending new result under `id="b"`.